# I have a problem with space appearing under my nested table. How do I expand the nested table to take up the whole vertical height of the cell

Tags: reporting-services, merge, ssrs-2008, reporting, rdlc

report Desing
[image]
I have 2 tablix in one tablix like this
[image]
i want tablix 2 take same size (height) of tablix 1
[image]

Comment: i want tablix 2 take same height of tablix 2 if possible

Comment: Please don't use the comments to add more information unless you are responding to a comment, instead edit your question. I suggest you show your report design as it's not clear how this is configured.

Comment: It looks like you have a row of data for Methodologie with a NULL Elements that is caussing the blank row.

Comment: Actually is a nested tablix and because group description wraps in multiple lines it leaves empty space.

Comment: No I don t have null element  line height is the problem when i make the tablix line heignt grand he work but when i make the line height small he make this

Comment: Abandon nesting to emulate vertical merged cells. For each Element du Module group use the first cell of Note/20  to write the sum of the outer group and expressions to handle borders and make the cell look like one. You cant handle sizing of nested tablix

Comment: can you explain more please

Comment: I have 3 tablix first is container and the second is "elemnt du module,ecrit,tp" and the 3 tablix is "Ecrit, tp" but he is inside first tablix

Comment: i have a group with ''Semestre" and "Module"

Comment: the tablix 2 and tablix 3 he don t fill cell

Comment: Note/20 is sum of group module

Comment: my question please is how to make tablix fill cells

Comment: set the cells to the exact same size then set set `CanGrow` and `CanShrink` to `false`. If this does not give you what you want I think you will have to accept it's not possible and redesign your report with some compromises.

Comment: i can t do that because i have data wrap if i set to cangrow to false same data hide

Comment: this problem cause because cell of "Note/20" i want to merge row cell but he don t accept but why table not fill cell????